# Finding extremes of a function in some domain

Tags: calculus

Find extreme values of the function

$$f(x,y)=e^{xy}$$

subject to constraints $x^2 + y^2 = 2$

---

What I have so far:

I know the gradient of f is

$$\nabla f(x,y) = \langle e^{xy}y,e^{xy}x\rangle$$

I set the components equal to each other because individually, they both equal 0.

$$e^{xy}y=e^{xy}x$$

However, I get $y=x$ and that doesn't tell me too much about its extremes..not to mention the boundary $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ I have to check. What am I missing?

Comment: I changed $< e^{xy}y,e^{xy}x>$ to $\langle e^{xy}y,e^{xy}x\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You have constraint, so Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want points where the gradient $e^{xy}\langle y,x\rangle$ is a scalar multiple of the gradient of $x^2+y^2$, which is $2\langle x,y\rangle$.  This implies that $x=y$.  So you're looking for points on the circle $x^2+y^2= 2$ at which $x=y$.  If $x^2+y^2=2$ and $x=y$, then $x^2+x^2=2$, so $x^2=1$ and $x=\pm1$.

There's not reason to set anything equal to $0$ in what I did above.

Comment: So, after finding x to be ±1, I plug this back into my constraints, yielding critical points $(1,1);(1,-1);(-1,1);(-1,-1)$ and $(0,0)$ from before ?

Comment: No: you still have the conclusion that $x=y$, so you'd have $(x,y)=(-1,-1)$ or $(x,y)=(1,1)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oh, right! and since I'm not being asked for absolute maximums/minimums, these points  $(x,y)=(−1,−1)$ or $(x,y)=(1,1)$ qualify under the umbrella term, 'extremes'.

Comment: You can conclude they're extremes because a non-constant continuous function on a closed bounded set in Euclidean space has an absolute maximum and an absolute minimum. (And $x^2+y^2=2$ is a closed bounded set in the Euclidean plane.)  But there are cases in which some points at which Lagrange multipliers exist are not extremes.